# Ableton Live 11 Lite: Lagging or distorted delay of recording

Tags: audio, ableton-live

I'm using Ableton Live 11 Lite while recording a cover, and discovered that all of my recording comes out as a jittery mess all of the sudden. I'm using a Focusrite Scarlett Solo, a Squier Telecaster, Maestro Ranger Over-Drive pedal, and an Audio-Technica Mic. It's a new project, I have a metronome set up for recording Privately Owned Spiral Galaxy, and the audio interface splits the mic and guitar into separate tracks that I'm trying to record individually. I posted a sample of the God-awful sound of it recording [here](https://youtu.be/KJXwrX9B5B4) for reference.

P.S. I know this isn't the correct page but there's hardly any Ableton/DAW questions on the Music page and no answers really, as opposed to the several I found on SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is strictly focused on programming questions I’m afraid. What I’d recommend is actually an Ableton forum. I’d maybe double check Ableton is the problem by trying some other DAWs. If you get the same problem is Reaper and Audacity, then you’ll know it is something to do with the interface, drivers or hardware rather than the DAW.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with playing with your buffer size in your Audio driver.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).